# Updating linux causes a sudden shader compilation failure on a previously working project

Tags: arch-linux, opengl

I am working on a large window manager project in Linux (the codebase is not mine). I run Arch Linux, and recently ran a system update.

Before the update, everything ran fine.  Now, after successfully compiling and launching my window manager, I receive the following runtime error:

```
Checking Framebuffer "Display Scratch Frame Buffer": Framebuffer is Incomplete for Unknown Reasons
Successfully created framebuffer "Display Scratch Frame Buffer": 1080x1920 (texture size: 1080x1920)
Loading shader: SHADER_MOTORCARMESHDISTORTION

Shader compilation failed.
```

**Question:** What aspect of my Linux system update could be causing this?

I think, among the things that were updated, were my `nvidia` drivers and possibly `mesa` and `cairo`. But does anyone have a more specific clue as to what I should be looking at?

Comment: I think it is related to opengl.

Comment: @Luciano: So would you look primarily into de-updating mesa?

Comment: I dont have Arch Linux here, only Debian GNU/Linux if i have something like this  i first will try to downgrade everything related to opengl, not only mesa.

Comment: See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/downgrading_packages for official (and AUR) Arch downgrade methods.  I think if you start there and dig around you will find that officially you should do a rollback of all packages to the some date before you did the upgrade, and that rolling back a single package is not supported.  I recently did a full "rollback" using a ZFS snapshot after a python upgrade broke my program. I intend to just wait until all the python libraries I need via `pip` are sufficiently upgraded.